# Can the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ be made continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Can the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ be made continuous at $(0,0)$ by defining $f(0,0)$ to be a specific value?

I say yes. I solved it this way:

$y=x \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{x^2+x^2} \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2x^2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$

Is my thinking on this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because if $y=0$ then your limit would be $1$. It is therefore impossible to extend this function continuously.

Comment: Interesting.  So this limit does not exist and therefore cannot be made continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I take the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $x\to0$ along the line $y=x$. I then have
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2+x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{2x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
However, if I take it along the line $y=0$, I have
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2+0}=\lim_{x\to0}1=1$$
Your approach is valid only if the limits are the same for all possible lines through the origin - which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** To make your function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ continuous at $(0,0)$,
ensure that $$\lim_\limits{\frac{x\to 0^+}{y\to 0^+}} f(x,y)= \lim_\limits{\frac{x\to 0^-}{y\to 0^-}} f(x,y)= f(0,0)$$

Is it possible?